Row to column conversion in SQL - Dynamic rows
I am trying to convert the rows into column. However, the number of rows/ names are not predictable. it varies each time when I ran it based on my condition. Is there an easy way to pull that info.

Current output of my query:
WarehouseCode   BinNum      splitdata   orderOfSeg  lengthOfSeg
test1          PR870B1/2    PR870B1     1   7
test1          PR870B1/2    2           2   1
test2          PR870B1/2    PR870B1         1   7
test2          PR870B1/2    2           2   1

How I like to see the end result:
WarehouseCode   BinNum      seg1       seg 2   seg 3....   lengthOfSeg1   LengthOfSeg2  lengthofSeg3.....
test1           PR870B1/2   PR870B1 2                 7              1
test2           PR870B1/2   PR870B1 2                 7              1

How can I achieve this in SQL Server?

look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query it explainbs dynamic pivot

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Is that possible to achieve in SQL Server? - yes - don't you actually want to ask How can I achieve this in SQL Server?

And please don't duplicate text to meet the question limit... that just annoys people. Take a bit longer to write a better question.

Current output of my query - where is this query? We need to see it.
